# Durrett (Probability : Theory and Examples ) Exercise 4.2.6

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

> Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ be non-negative i.i.d random variable with
> $EY_m=1$ and $P(Y_m=1)<1 $. $X_n=\Pi_{1\leq m\leq n}Y_m$ is martingale. Use
> the strong law of large numbers to conclude $(1/n)\log X_n \rightarrow c <0$.

To use strong law of large number, I think $E|\log Y_i|<\infty$ is needed. However , if $P(Y_i=0)>0$, how could this possible?

Comment: Suppose that $P(Y_1=0)>0$. Then $\frac{1}{n}\log(X_n)\to-\infty$, so if you allow for $c=-\infty$ there is no problem here.

Comment: If $P(Y_1=0)>0$, shouldn't$\frac{1}{n}log(X_n) \rightarrow - \frac{\infty}{\infty}$ be also possible?

Comment: No. If $P(Y_1=0)>0$ then almost surely $X_n=0$ for all $n$ large enough. So $\frac{1}{n}\log(X_n)=-\infty$ for all $n$ large enough with probability $1$.